# Retrieving a java object(arraylist/hashmap) from struts 1.xx action via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, action, struts-1

I have a requirement (Java EE application based on struts 1.xx) in which I have to fetch a Java object from a Struts action class via AJAX in order to display on the UI and render it in the form of a table.

The object will be dynamic as it will be populated via a web service, which will be called in the action itself.

Is there anyway to fetch the object via AJAX (javascript/jquery)? The action will be called when clicking on UI tabs and I have to display the response (arraylist/hashmap object) of the action in that particular tab.

**Please see, I'm working on an existing application and i'm bound to use Struts 1.xx framework only.**

Below are the steps I will perform in the action class:

```
public class AjaxAction extends Action {
public ActionForward execute(final ActionMapping mapping, final ActionForm form,
            final HttpServletRequest request,final HttpServletResponse response)

    {       
        // Step1 :webservice call
                    //Step 2: parse the webservice reponse and place it inside a hashmap or arraylist object

                return null;
    }
}
```

Step3: To fetch the populated hashmap/arraylist object via ajax and display it on UI which im not sure how to do that. 
Any examples or pointers to some tutorials will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery ajax .

[jQuery ajax](http://www.raistudies.com/struts-1/ajax-with-struts-example/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my requirement is not to fetch a single or multiple predefined text values but to fetch n- number of different java obejcts (string, integer, etc.) on the output.In short i want an encapsulated java object output on ajax not just a text output.

Comment: @user1697113 You don't get "Java objects" in a response, you get text. How you *interpret* that text is what changes. For example, you could return the objects serialized to JSON.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense i was not aware of this limitation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As for my problem i found an easy solution, i am not sure if it answers my question but it helped me to work around.

I used the Jquery Ui tabs framework http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Rather than getting a whole object from action it has the facility to call the action itself.
This can be done by providing the url for action in the tab itself.

```
<li><a href="myAction.do">CALL a JSP VIA AJAX</a></li>
```

Now this tab, will load another jsp which will be called by action itself. Hence, it donot have to send huge data via ajax rather i can call the entire jsp in the tab by firing the action.